# Is there an exponential map in $\mathbb A^1$ homotopy theory?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory, motivic-homotopy

Let $k$ be a field, and let $Z \subset X$ be a smooth subscheme of a smooth scheme $X$.
When $k = \mathbb C$, there is a distinguished isotopy class of (topological) open embeddings $N_Z \to X$.  In particular, these induce a homotopy class of maps $N_Z - Z \to X - Z$.

Is there a similar construction of a homotopy class of maps $N_Z -Z \to X - Z$ in  the $\mathbb A^1$ homotopy category?

My hope was that such a map could be constructed using deformation to the normal cone. However, I found the paper "Motivic Tubular Neighborhoods" by Levine which may suggest that an elementary construction does not exist. In section 4.2 an exponential map is constructed stably.  Is it possible to construct an unstable version using similar methods?   I would also be interested in a natural map $|N_Z - Z|^{et} \to |X-Z|^{et}$ between the etale realizations.

Comment: Is Theorem 2.23 of Morel-Voevodsky's "$A^1$-homotopy theory of schemes" fine for you? I suspect that Levine actually needed something more complicated for his own purposes.

Comment: @MikhailBondarko No, I should clarify that I am aware of the purity theorem and I would really like the exponential map itself, and not the equivalence  $Th(N_Z) \simeq X/(X-Z)$.

Comment: There is a canonical isomorphism between these two things in the $A^1$-homotopy category. If this is not what you want, then may you explain what do you actually need?

Comment: @MikhailBondarko  As I said in my question,  I want to construct a map $N_Z - Z \to X-Z$ unstably.  My question is not about $X/(X-Z)$ or the Thom space.